# Only half of the line visible in GNU Octave command window and editor in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: user-interface, editor, ubuntu-14.04, octave

I have attached screenshot for clarity regarding the question. Restarting the system or re-installing(by purging first) does not seem to work. The command line version of gnu-octave works fine.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: IIRC, to avoid this you have to compile and build octave with Qt4, not Qt5.

Comment: which GNU Octave version? Installed from ubuntu repository or from source? try to delete `~/.config/octave` which resets all your GUI settings

Comment: Thank you @Andy, I use Ubuntu 16.04 and I had the same problem, but it got fixed after deleting that directory.

Answer (score 3):

`delete ~/.config/octave` and
run octave.

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows and wasn't able to find the config file suggested by Matheus. I solved it through the GUI by going to Menu-->Window-->Reset Default Window Layout